# Save a shapefile in a temporary file

Tags: shapefile, r, shiny

I would like to add a line after the transformation of my shapefile in order to save it in a temporary file.

```
uploadShpfile <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$shp)) {
      inFile <- input$shp
      inFolder <- substr(inFile$datapath, 1, nchar(inFile$datapath) - 5)
      unzip(inFile$datapath, exdir = inFolder)
      shpDF <- input$shp
      pwd <- getwd()
      updir <- dirname(shpDF$datapath[1])
      setwd(updir)
      for (i in 1:nrow(shpDF)) {
        file.rename(shpDF$datapath[i], shpDF$name[i])
      }
      shpName <- shpDF$name[grep(x = shpDF$name, pattern = "*.shp")]
      shpPath <- paste(updir, shpName, sep = "/")
      setwd(pwd)
      shpFile <- readOGR(shpPath)
      shpFile <- spTransform(shpFile,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to save to temporary shapefile the last line could be something like:
`shapefile(shpFile, tempfile(pattern = "", fileext = ".shp"))`

Comment: Hello Monchill, thank you for the reply. "shapefile" is not found as a function. What can I write instead?

Comment: Okay I found the problem. I didn't had the package "raster". Thank you @Monchill. You were very helpful :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have included the required package list. Good that you found the solution!